# Why does the JSON response to my AJAX POST display in the browser when I submit a form in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

While this may not be best practice, this is how a friend taught me how to do this and its what I'm most comfortable with.

I post my form to the Controller with an ajax .post() call, the controller does whatever it needs to do and then returns a Json back:

```
// View
@Html.BeginForm()
{
    // whatever form controls are neeeded
}

<button class="btn btn-default">Create</button> @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")

<div class="modal fade" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="modal-message"></p>
                <p class="modal-message-extra"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="lnkMoreDetail">More Detail</a>
                <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("form").submit();

        // I handled this this way, because I'm not sure if the below
        // function with an actual submit input type might cause problems...
    });

    $("form").submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                if (!data.IsOK) {
                    $("h4.modal-title").html(data.Title);
                    $("p.modal-message").html(data.Message);
                    $("p.modal-message-extra").html(data.Error).hide();
                    $("#modalDialog").modal();

                    // show more detail button only if error value exists
                    if (data.Error != "") {
                        $("#lnkMoreDetail").hide();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // display a modal windows confirming success
                    // then redirect to the Index view
                }
                return;
            });

            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#lnkMoreDetail").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "More Detail") {
            $(this).text("Less Detail");
            $("p.modal-message-extra").show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).text("More Detail");
            $("p.modal-message-extra").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here's the Controller:

```
// Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserViewModel Source)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // map view model to data model and add to database

            return Json(new { Message = "Success", "IsOK = true });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // sends a JSON back to the view that details
            // the error that occurred
            return ReportError(ex, "Register User");
        }
    }
}
```

When I submit the form, I get the following (this is directly copied from my browser)

> {"Message":"Success","IsOK":true}

Happy that the JSON return is working, but why isn't it displaying modals?

Comment: call a method other than create. write your controller logic in some other method not the one that returns view

Comment: @coder771 can you share your thought process on that? I'm not following...

Comment: What's happening inside your "else" in your javascript?

Comment: @jpgrassi same as is happening inside the first part of the if statement, but it shows a modal with a success message and then uses a setTimeout to redirect the user back to the list after a short delay so that the user can actually read the modal

Comment: the reason it is happening, you are not returning view but the json result and that is what it is displaying...check if data==success then location= location.href

Comment: for reference http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/mvc-curd-operation-using-jquery-json-and-linq-to-sql-class/

Comment: @coder771 thanks, I'll implement changes tomorrow at work and update

Comment: @coder771 still working on this just fyi... things have been crazy here!

Comment: rather then returning json try returning some view. your post method is returning json and not  view that is reason it displays in browser